# SonarQube and Karma code coverage - unresolved file paths

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, karma-coverage

I searched a lot for this specific error, but I had no chance in finding a suitable answer.

I have SonarQube 5.4 and using newest Karma-version.

Following error occurs when running sonar-runner:

```
INFO: Analysing /Users/foo/repository/BarJS/test/reports/coverage/lcov.info
INFO: Could not resolve 6 file paths in lcov.info, first unresolved path: /Users/foo/repository/BarJS/test/spec/Classname.test.js
```

While foo is my username and BarJS is the name of the project.

Other people getting those errors having mispelled or case-specific or relative paths. I checked half a dozen times. *My paths are correct.*

I have absolute paths in my Karma lcov.info-file. All camelcase letters are equal to their path in Finder.

Content of Karmas lcov.info

```
SF:/Users/foo/repository/BarJS/test/spec/Classname.test.js
```

Anybody out there having same issue? It is really annoying

Comment: Do you import this file into SQ?

Comment: Yeah, but not manually. I use sonar.properties in my project folder with this argument: sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning file "Classname.test.js"

Comment: do you have "/Users/foo/repository/BarJS/test/spec/Classname.test.js" included in "sonar.sources"?

Comment: @ElenaVilchik: No, not included. There is only reference to my JS files, not my tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the solution was to add

```
sonar.tests=test/spec
```

to my sonar.properties. Now it is working like a charm

@ElenaVilchik: many thx for your direction, helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue. Sonar scanner log shows  `first unresolved path: ./app/modules/abc.js` as the error. The reason for my issue was, my `sonar-project.properties` file was in a parent directory rather than `app` folder. I could be able to solve the issue by changing the directory paths in `lcov.info` file to relative paths from the directory which is `sonar-project.properties` resides.

ex: `sonar-project.properties` file was in a folder called `WebContent`. `lcov.info` file shows `SF:./app/modules/abc.js` as file path. After changing this to `SF:./WebContent/app/modules/abc.js`, test result published to sonar without any issue.